# scripts not showing in custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

So, I've built my own theme for wordpress. Now, I'm trying to put my own plug-in on that theme which requires 3 javascript files. Upon reading the WP-Codex, it tells me the wp_register_script, wp_enqueue_script and add_action methods are the best way to go.

Now, in my plug-in file, I've done things such as:

```
function register_my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('script-1', plugins_url('path/to/script-1.js'), array('jquery'));
    wp_register_script('script-2', plugins_url('path/to/script-2.js'));

    wp_enqueue_script('script-1');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-2');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts');
```

Nothing seems to show up on any of my template pages. I've even put this code on the main index page and still nothing. I've written something simple, straight from the codex like: wp_enqueue_script('jquery') on the page and still nothing shows up. Is there something I'm missing here? Why won't html for loading the scripts show up on my page?

Also, I'm running Wordpress 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enqueue my scripts like this on the **functions.php** file:

### PHP

`wp_enqueue_script ('customjs', '/wp-content/themes/blackboard/js/custom.js','','',true);`

Please remember that the usage is:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer); ?>`

Try putting the `wp_enqueue_script()` on your functions.php just as a test. Please check that your path is correct too and check the source code to see if it's printing but just with a wrong path.

Note that the first line of code on this answer is the only thing I need to enqueue the script, nothing else as far as I know.

Let us know if this works for you, cheers.

Comment: The problem is, the HTML that is supposed to be generated isn't even showing up. Whether I put wp_enqueue_script() in the actual theme file, functions file or my plugin file. I've tested it with the supposed libraries that Wordpress caries (I.E., jquery) but still nothing.

It doesnt seem to work on the admin-init hook either...

Comment: Wait a sec... I'm feeling pretty dull at the moment. I forgot to put in the wp_head() function in my theme. So yeah... It's working. Guess little details like that can be overlooked when you're tired at 2am in the morning.